# Upgrade to Angular 8: Changing the target to "es2015" in tsconfig.json leads to error in polyfills-2015

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, polyfills

When changing the target to **es2015** (instead of es5), I get the following error when starting my app:

```
polyfills-es2015.4a168e5d0734802f67ed.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'true' of undefined
    at Object.6dTf (polyfills-es2015.4a168e5d0734802f67ed.js:1)
    at u (runtime-es2015.05393c8efcd0eb158773.js:1)
    at Module.hN/g (polyfills-es2015.4a168e5d0734802f67ed.js:1)
    at u (runtime-es2015.05393c8efcd0eb158773.js:1)
    at Object.1 (polyfills-es2015.4a168e5d0734802f67ed.js:1)
    at u (runtime-es2015.05393c8efcd0eb158773.js:1)
    at t (runtime-es2015.05393c8efcd0eb158773.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.05393c8efcd0eb158773.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.4a168e5d0734802f67ed.js:1
```

Also, I needed to **import Zone.js in my main.ts** file instead of polyfills.ts, otherwise I would get the error:

> in this configuration angular requires zone.js

I am using Angular8, Typescript 3.4.5 and node 12.4.0. What am I doing wrong?

My **tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc/app",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from **web-animations-js**.

Since Angular 6, it is **no longer needed**:

> We’ve updated our implementation of Animations to no longer need the
>   web animations polyfill. This means that you can remove this polyfill
>   from your application and save approximately 47KB of bundle size,
>   while increasing animations performance in Safari at the same time.

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills

I removed it from polyfills and from my package.json and the error disappeared.